# What is the advantage of using nuxt-link over router-link?

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js, nuxt-link

In `Nuxt`, we can use `router-link` as well as `nuxt-link`. What is the advantage of using `nuxt-link` over `router-link`?

```
<nuxt-link to="/about">About</nuxt-link>
```

instead of

```
<router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to **[Nuxt Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-link/)**, two important points:

> *This component (*`<nuxt-link>`*) is used to provide navigations between page components and **enhance performances** with **smart prefetching**.*

> *In fact, `<nuxt-link>` extends `<router-link>`. That means it takes*
> *the same properties and can be used in the same manner.*

After that we can read about **[smart prefetching](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/introducing-smart-prefetching/)**:

> *Nuxt.js will automagically prefetch the code-splitted pages linked*
> *with  when visible in the viewport by default. This hugely*
> *improves the end user performances.*

Based on that I think you are simply looking at better performance with `<nuxt-link>`.

Comment: For anyone interested: According to [this article](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-individual-vue-components-and-prefetching/), `If you’re using Vue CLI 3 every lazily loaded resource is prefetched by default!`

Comment: Bad if you want to share your base components between a Nuxt and a non-nuxt project